# Countries with loose regulations

Tags: law, geopolitics, regulation

I'm writing a story about a villain (as some would call him) or antihero (as he would prefer to be called), somewhat similar to Adrian Veidt, who needs to buy a few hundred acres of land to set up facilities and carry out certain plans.

He's from the US, but he needs a place where there won't be any nosy officials coming around to check on compliance with environmental regulations, or working conditions, or how he came by certain consignments of goods, or why his security guards are toting so much firepower.

At the same time, he needs to be able to fly home at regular intervals and do business in the US, so he can't have the FBI accusing him of doing business with a rogue state. Everything needs to look reasonably legitimate from a distance.

He doesn't yet have any connections outside the US, but he can pay a few million dollars in bribes if need be.

What would be the best country for him to set up shop in?

Comment: There are always nosy officials you need to pay off. That is why they became officials in the first place. So, you are looking for a place where they don't have many regulations, hay will cost the least amount in bribes. I would suggest any county with a good US$ to [government $] conversion. That will make your 2 million go the furthest.

Comment: @user1873 I'm not sure number of regulations even matters that much; if you have lots of regulations but can bribe one higher-up to get all of them ignored, that's better than a handful of regulations each of which are enforced by principled sorts.

Comment: This would be better asked over at worldbuilding.se (That said, pretty much any country would work if you have a few million in bribes at your disposal...)

Comment: Liberland. Look it up on Wikipedia. Since it's relatively new and doesn't have a solid structure to it's government yet (other than being really liberal), you could take quite a bit of artistic liberty with it.

Comment: @Tyler, Liberland is only 3 square miles. I think people would take notice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your character should try to buy his lands in **Paraguay**.

[Paraguay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraguay) is a South America country, one of the poorest and the second most corrupted (first is Venezuela) in the region. In America, Paraguay is known where the best marijuana farming is; being in the middle of everything, makes the country geopolitically and strategically well placed to make illegal business. Most drugs routes pass through Paraguay in the border with Brazil and Argentina; but not only for drugs. The smuggling is almost a culture in Pedro Juan Caballero, Ciudad del Este or Salto del Guaira (PY), Clorinda, Resistencia, Iguazú(ARG), Guaira, Foz de Iguacu, Matto Grosso (BRA). Most of contraband's offices are placed in Paraguay, where the control is almost null; there is a small control but they can be bribed.

Authorities in Paraguay are very likely to receive or stimulate the internal corruption. The environmental agency has almost no power to act, almost 70% of the work population are in the informal economy; those who are working in the formal economy are exploited, working more than 12 hours for less of USD 20 per day or USD 2 per hour.

The USD is a good money too. 1 USD = 5,000 PYG and it's a lot.

Buy a land [is very easy also](http://www.abc.com.py/edicion-impresa/economia/supuesta-triple-corrupcion-en-una-posible-compra-de-tierras-del-indert-447873.html). You don't need, in most cases, a lot of documents or proofs about your identity nor your money's origin; if this is a problem, just ask for a mediator, which putting his name in your lands; and, if anything happen with your lands, he's the guilty and not your character. Don't worry about the institutions which regulate and control the lands, they have several problems to solve. The Police is very corrupted, especially in the countryside, where the soybean farmers(some of them), narcotraffickers and ranchers (some of them) work together, especially in the border cities previously appointed.

Your character won't have any problem to do business with the United States. The United States supported a dictatorship in Paraguay from 1954 to 1989, where some military and politic officials were involved in narcotic trafficking, money laundering, hide nazi officials or bride international authorities, but still, they have good relationship with DEA agents, with the Department of State or with the ambassador. The same thing goes for most businessman. In fact, the current President of the Republic, Horacio Cartes, was acussed by the DEA ([Wikileaks' files](https://wikileaks.org/cable/2010/01/10BUENOSAIRES5.html)) of being involved in several cases of smuggling cigarettes, cocaine trafficking, money laundering and others. However, with all these accusations or investigations, Cartes Group (Cartes' companies) has a soda factory in Texas, United States and no problem to invest there.

***EXTRA:*** For a little inspiration, you should check the movie "[Luna de Cigarras](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9S5ijb0Kbpg&html5=1)". The movie is about an American who wants to buy some lands to grow drugs in the border with Brazil.

Comment: I'd add that in such a place it would be relatively easy to get his middle-man to pay off both the local government and the police to accommodate him. If he had both in a co-operative mood, he could do whatever he pleased and nobody local would be able to do anything about it.